# Firebase crashlytics has crashes in libc.so unknown

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I get a lot of errors in a library called libc.so
We don't have any native code in our project so I'm wondering if these are coming from one of our dependencies.
If so, how do I understand which library is causing this issue?

Crash 1

```
Crashed: Thread :  SIGABRT  0x000027bf00002899
#00 pc 0x787cf895ac libc.so 
#01 pc 0x787cf8957c libc.so 
#02 pc 0x77fc6da720 libart.so 
#03 pc 0x78801dd600 libbase.so 
#04 pc 0x77fc666a3c libart.so 
#05 pc 0x77fc66e4b0 libart.so 
#06 pc 0x77fc67c68c libart.so 
#07 pc 0x77fc6e7b84 libart.so 
#08 pc 0x77fc6fbacc libart.so 
#09 pc 0x77fc6fab60 libart.so 
#10 pc 0x787cfe86f0 libc.so 
#11 pc 0x787cf8b0e8 libc.so
```

Crash 2

```
Crashed: Thread :  SIGTRAP  0x000027a0000005f5
#00 pc 0x773bbea6b4 base.apk 
#01 pc 0x773bbea560 base.apk 
#02 pc 0x773d1d3cb0 base.apk 
#03 pc 0x773a570408 base.apk 
#04 pc 0x773c2bfea0 base.apk 
#05 pc 0x773c220278 base.apk 
#06 pc 0x773cbd7d08 base.apk 
#07 pc 0x773cbd7ccc base.apk 
#08 pc 0x773cbd7c54 base.apk 
#09 pc 0x7819831dbc libutils.so 
#10 pc 0x78198319c4 libutils.so 
#11 pc 0x781baff63c libandroid_runtime.so 
#12 pc 0x703cc724  
#13 pc 0x6fcb192c  
#14 pc 0x6fc7b61c  
#15 pc 0x71af7f24 boot-framework.oat 
#16 pc 0x703cc9cc  
#17 pc 0x71536f88 boot-framework.oat 
#18 pc 0x6f84119c  
#19 pc 0x6f8a9aac  
#20 pc 0x6fff698c  
#21 pc 0x6f8ad0a4  
#22 pc 0x6fc859dc  
#23 pc 0x71af4a78 boot-framework.oat 
#24 pc 0x702570c4  
#25 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#26 pc 0x6f8ad3b4  
#27 pc 0x6f8ad3b4  
#28 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#29 pc 0x6ffc7f44  
#30 pc 0x717cfb30 boot-framework.oat 
#31 pc 0x703f966c  
#32 pc 0x703f8294  
#33 pc 0x779791bc04 libart.so 
#34 pc 0x77975495b8 libart.so 
#35 pc 0x703f966c  
#36 pc 0x77975581c4 libart.so 
#37 pc 0x703f966c  
#38 pc 0x703f966c  
#39 pc 0x77978ce508 libart.so 
#40 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#41 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#42 pc 0x77979ac218 libart.so 
#43 pc 0x703f966c  
#44 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#45 pc 0x703f966c  
#46 pc 0x77978cff30 libart.so 
#47 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#48 pc 0x70e01da0 boot.oat 
#49 pc 0x6f9dd14c  
#50 pc 0x6f8cf454  
#51 pc 0x70e05478 boot.oat 
#52 pc 0x6f9dd8f4  
#53 pc 0x6fa8c78c  
#54 pc 0x6fc80bbc  
#55 pc 0x6f8cf454  
#56 pc 0x6f7b39e4  
#57 pc 0x71d73fa0 boot-framework.oat 
#58 pc 0x703abf6c  
#59 pc 0x71d73b4c boot-framework.oat 
#60 pc 0x703abef4  
#61 pc 0x700543bc  
#62 pc 0x700543bc  
#63 pc 0x71d781c8 boot-framework.oat
```

crash 3

```
Crashed: Thread :  SIGABRT  0x000027ce00006d26
#00 pc 0x7c556075ac libc.so 
#01 pc 0x7c5560757c libc.so 
#02 pc 0x7bd26da720 libart.so 
#03 pc 0x7c56d77600 libbase.so 
#04 pc 0x7bd2666a3c libart.so 
#05 pc 0x7bd266e4b0 libart.so 
#06 pc 0x7bd267c68c libart.so 
#07 pc 0x7bd26e7b84 libart.so 
#08 pc 0x7bd26fbacc libart.so 
#09 pc 0x7bd26fab60 libart.so 
#10 pc 0x7c556666f0 libc.so 
#11 pc 0x7c556090e8 libc.so
```

Comment: Any news about this?